# Problems setting up initial array for checkers game board

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner to C++, working my way through "Jumping Into C++". I'm learning arrays and am trying to put a basic checkers game together, and I'm having a heck of a time getting my initial array representing the board to work correctly.  In particular, row 10 is displaying values that I wouldn't expect.  I would expect the values to be:

[10][2][10][2][10][2][10][2][10][2]

Instead, it's:

[10][2][10][2][10][**10**][10][2][10][**1**] (highlighting the two values that are not appearing as I expect).

I'm confirming the values at lines 265 and 288 (marked "//WTF?") by displaying the values of several elements and am getting:
Space 6,10 = 0
Space 10,10 = 1

Based on the "for" statements that I'm using to set up the initial values, I don't understand why these two values are getting set improperly.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//intializing functions
string displaySpace( int array[10][10], int x, int y );
bool validPlayerOneMoveCheck( int array[][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row );
bool validPlayerTwoMoveCheck( int array[][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row );
void movePiece( int array[][10], int player, int otherPlayer, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row );
void jumpPiece( int array[][10], int player, int otherPlayer, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row );
//void checkKing ( int array[][10], int player, int move_column, int move_row );

int otherPlayerDefine( int player )
{
    int otherPlayer = 0;
    if ( player == 1 )
    {
        otherPlayer = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        otherPlayer = 1;
    }
    return otherPlayer;
}

bool validPieceCheck( int array[10][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row )
{
    bool validPiece = 0;

    if ( piece_column < 1 || piece_column > 10 || piece_row < 1 || piece_row > 10 )
    {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid space number.\n";
    }
    else if ( array[piece_row][piece_column] == player || array[piece_row][piece_column] == player + 2 )
    {
        validPiece = 1;  // this is a valid space and a valid piece
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You do not have a piece at position " << piece_column << ", " << piece_row << "\n";
    }
    return validPiece;
}

bool validMoveCheck( int array[10][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    bool validMove = 0;
    if ( move_column < 1 || move_column > 10 || move_row < 1 || move_row > 10 || array[move_row][move_column] == 10 )
    {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid space number.\n";
    }
    else if ( array[move_row][move_column] != 0 )
    {
        cout << "That space is already occupied.\n";
    }
    else if ( array[piece_row][piece_column] == 1 )  //player one normal piece
    {
        validMove = validPlayerOneMoveCheck( array, player, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        cout << "Player One Move Check, normal piece\n";
    }
    else if ( array[piece_row][piece_column] == 2 )  //player two normal piece
    {
        validMove = validPlayerTwoMoveCheck( array, player, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        cout << "Player Two Move Check, normal piece\n";
    }
    else if ( array[piece_row][piece_column] == 3 || array[piece_row][piece_column] == 4 )  //either player king
    {
        bool validMove01 = validPlayerOneMoveCheck( array, player, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        bool validMove02 = validPlayerTwoMoveCheck( array, player, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        cout << "King Piece Move Check\n";
        if ( validMove01 == 1 || validMove02 == 1 )
        {
            validMove = 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid move\n";
    }
    cout << "validMove = " << validMove << "\n";

    //check if kinged
    //checkKing ( array, player, move_column, move_row );

    return validMove;
}

//player 1 valid move check from top of board (low numbers) to bottom (higher numbers)
bool validPlayerOneMoveCheck( int array[][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    bool validMove;
    int otherPlayer = otherPlayerDefine( player );
    //moving one space to empty space; empty space verified in ValidMoveCheck already
    if (( move_column == piece_column + 1 || move_column == piece_column - 1) && ( move_row == piece_row + 1 ))
        {
            validMove = 1;
            movePiece( array, player, otherPlayer, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        }
    //jumping another player
    else if (( move_column == piece_column + 2 && move_row == piece_row + 2 && array[piece_row + 1][piece_column + 1] == otherPlayer ) ||
        ( move_column == piece_column - 2 && move_row == piece_row + 2 && array[piece_row + 1][piece_column - 1] == otherPlayer ))
        {
            validMove = 1;
            jumpPiece( array, player, otherPlayer, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        }
    cout << "validPlayerOneMoveCheck = " << validMove << "\n";
    return validMove;
}

//player 2 valid move check from top of board (low numbers) to bottom (higher numbers)
bool validPlayerTwoMoveCheck( int array[][10], int player, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    bool validMove;
    int otherPlayer = otherPlayerDefine( player );
    //moving one space to empty space; empty space verified in ValidMoveCheck already
    if (( move_column == piece_column + 1 || move_column == piece_column - 1) && ( move_row == piece_row - 1 ))
        {
            validMove = 1;
            movePiece( array, player, otherPlayer, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        }
    //jumping another player
    else if (( move_column == piece_column + 2 && move_row == piece_row - 2 && array[piece_row - 1][piece_column + 1] == otherPlayer ) ||
        ( move_column == piece_column - 2 && move_row == piece_row - 2 && array[piece_row - 1][piece_column - 1] == otherPlayer ))
        {
            validMove = 1;
            jumpPiece( array, player, otherPlayer, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        }
        // NEED TO DEAL WITH JUMPING SOMEWHERE!! -
    cout << "validPlayerTwoMoveCheck = " << validMove << "\n";
    return validMove;
}

void movePiece( int array[][10], int player, int otherPlayer, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    //move player piece
    cout << "movePiece called \n";
    array[piece_row][piece_column] = 0;
    array[move_row][move_column] = player;
}

void jumpPiece( int array[][10], int player, int otherPlayer, int piece_column, int piece_row, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    cout << "jumpPiece called \n";
    cout << "Player " << player << ", you took Player " << otherPlayer << "'s piece!\n";
    array[piece_row][piece_column] = 0;
    array[move_row][move_column] = player;
    array[(move_row + piece_row)/2][(move_column + piece_column)/2] = 0;
}

/*
void checkKing ( int array[][10], int player, int move_column, int move_row )
{
    if ( player == 1 && move_row == 10 && array[move_row][move_column] != 3 )
    {
        array[move_row][move_column] = 3;
        cout << "Player 1, you got a king!";
    }
    else if ( player == 2 && move_row == 1 && array[move_row][move_column] != 4 )
    {
        array[move_row][move_column] = 4;
        cout << "Player 1, you got a king!";
    }
}
*/

void displayBoard( int array[10][10] )
{
    cout << "     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10\n\n";
    for ( int i = 1; i < 11; i+=2 )
    {
        cout << i << "   [" << displaySpace( array, i, 1) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i, 3) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i, 5) << "]   ["
            << displaySpace( array, i, 7) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i, 9) << "]\n\n";
        if ( i < 9 )
        {
            cout << (i+1) << "      [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 2) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 4) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 6) <<
                "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 8) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 10) << "]\n\n";
        }
        else //this is to account for different spacing with "10" prefix
        {
            cout << (i+1) << "     [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 2) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 4) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 6) <<
                "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 8) << "]   [" << displaySpace( array, i+1, 10) << "]\n";
        }
    }
}

string displaySpace( int array[10][10], int x, int y )
//this converts integer values to characters to display to the player
{
    string display;
    switch ( array[x][y])
    {
        case 0:
            display = " ";
            break;
        case 1:
            display = "X";
            break;
        case 2:
            display = "O";
            break;
        case 3:
            display = "Y";
            break;
        case 4:
            display = "M";
            break;
        case 10:
            display = "";
            break;
    }
    return display;
}



int main()
{
    int board[10][10];
    bool game_over = 0;
    int player = 2;
    int piece_column;
    int piece_row;
    int move_column;
    int move_row;
    bool validPiece;
    bool validMove;

    //initial piece layout
   for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2 )
    {
        board[1][i] = 1;
        board[3][i] = 1;
        board[5][i] = 0;
        board[7][i] = 2;
        board[9][i] = 2;
        for ( int j = 2; j < 11; j+=2 )
        {
            board[j][i] = 10;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 2; i < 11; i+=2 )
    {
        board[2][i] = 1;
        board[4][i] = 1;
        board[6][i] = 0;
        board[8][i] = 2;
        board[10][i] = 2;
        //NO IDEA WHY THE BELOW "FOR" WON'T RUN - COMPILES FINE, BUT WON'T RUN
     /* for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j+=2 )
        {
            board[j][i] = 10;
        }  */
    }
    //WHEREAS THIS ONE WORKS FINE
    for ( int i = 2; i < 11; i+=2 )
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j+=2 )
        {
            board[j][i] = 10;
        }
    }

//WTF??
    cout << "Space 2, 1 = " << board[1][2] << "\n";
    cout << "Space 6, 10 = " << board[10][6] << "\n";
    cout << "Space 10, 10 = " << board[10][10] << "\n";


    do
    {
       //change player
        switch ( player )
        {
        case 1:
            player = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            player = 1;
            break;
        }

        //reset variables
        validPiece = 0;
        validMove = 0;

//WTF??
        cout << "Space 2, 1 = " << board[1][2] << "\n";
        cout << "Space 6, 10 = " << board[6][10] << "\n";
        cout << "Space 10, 10 = " << board[10][10] << "\n";

        do {
            do {
            cout << "\n\n";
            displayBoard( board );
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "Player " << player << ", make your move.\n";
            cout << "Select column of piece to move: ";
            cin >> piece_column;
            cout << "\nSelect row of piece to move: ";
            cin >> piece_row;
            validPiece = validPieceCheck( board, player, piece_column, piece_row );
            } while ( validPiece == 0 );
        validPiece = 0;
        cout << "\nSelect column to move to: ";
        cin >> move_column;
        cout << "\nSelect row to move to: ";
        cin >> move_row;
        cout << "\n";
        validMove = validMoveCheck( board, player, piece_column, piece_row, move_column, move_row );
        } while ( validMove == 0 );


    } while ( game_over == 0 );
```

Comment: Just a remark: The statements`Space 2,1` -> `board[1][2]` and `Space 6,10` -> `board[6][10]` are inconsistent

Comment: That for loop that "won't run" (as you mentioned in a comment) doesn't run because your array does not have an element at index 10. You know that the first element of an array has index 0 right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, AnotherTest.  I was just realizing that - I wasn't counting the elements of the array from zero, I was counting 1-10.  :/

Comment: Don't overlook @PhilipD's comment either.